# Paint and marker removal from minifigs?

Tags: minifigures, cleaning

When I was little, I sometimes painted or colored on LEGO minifigures. Is there an easier solution for cleaning off the marks, especially the paint? **Glass cleaner was recommended** but after leaving them in the cup for a while (a few hours, I believe), the marker and paint faded, but it was minimal. Is there anything else I could do to remove it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove printed decoration](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/how-to-remove-printed-decoration)

Comment: No, I don't think it does, because this one is getting off decals from LEGO, and not paint.

Comment: You mean your figures have decals on them and not paint?

Comment: Do you have a picture of minifigures before and after using windows cleaner?

Comment: @zovits I painted on the minifigures, not premade decals.

Comment: No, I don't have pictures, but the paint is indeed faded, but since I'm selling them I need them in top shape.